# Extend touch area on iPhone X in landscape mode

Tags: uiview, uikit, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

If a `UIViewController` is launched in *landscape mode*, even though the `home indicator` is not on the right side, still the rightmost 44 points on the screen do not respond to touches. I am wondering what is the purpose of disabling those pixels for touches and is there a way to extend the touch area on the right?

Comment: Can you post any relevant code? What view are you using the detect touches and what are its constraints?

Answer (score 0):

[**safearealayoutguide**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)

> When the view is visible onscreen, this guide reflects the portion of
>   the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars,
>   and other ancestor views. (In tvOS, the safe area reflects the area
>   not covered the screen's bezel.) If the view is not currently
>   installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet visible onscreen, the
>   layout guide edges are equal to the edges of the view.

As you try to add objects beyond safe area your content get chance clip by **Device Bazels.**

Example:
When you add button outside safe area as

```
let buttonOutsideSafeArea = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 44, height: 40))
buttonOutsideSafeArea.backgroundColor = .red
self.view.addSubview(buttonOutsideSafeArea)
```

**When you rotate right on device.**

[image]

**But it will get clipped(by Top Notch) when you rotate left**

[image]

> Hence try to avoid adding objects beyond safe Area